# What does 3AG mean in "Fuse Block 3AG"?

Tags: components, fuses

I have read from a vendor website. It mentions 3AG fuse block. What does 3AG mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3AG is a standard form factors for fuses.  It's very common.  3AG also known as "American fuse" (as opposed to "European fuse", which is smaller).

[image]
([source](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/Files/Littelfuse/Technical%20Resources/Documents/Data%20Sheets/313_315.pdf))

[image]
([source](http://www.jaycar.com.au/images_uploaded/fuseprmr.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

The "AG" means "Automotive Glass"